# Best Practice for creating Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, gwt, restlet

To preface I am new to web development. I am looking at creating a core set of RESTful web services around a valuable document library of sorts (initial CRUD abilities). In doing so I am theoretically creating a perfectly re-usable and scalable back-end to be used by unanticipated applications in the future.

My question centers around the best practice for doing this. My initial requirement has me also creating a unique front end. Would I make the front end and back end completely separate projects to enhance the re-usability. It would increase overhead.

Looking at using GWT, Restlet, and the Java EE technology stack if this influences the setup at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important is design a clean Java API - independent of REST, RMI, or whatever protocol you want to use.  From a clean Java API, you can support any access method.

Unless you have a use case for these other access methods, don't build them now.  You can build it when you need it.

The easiest interface to add initially is a web based interface where your web app runs in the same JVM as your core API.  I'd do this if this works for your use case.  Building a separate console application that accesses your core API via a REST (or whatever) protocol is a lot more work..

Comment: you are talking about the Java layer that actually interacts with the database correct?

Comment: Correct. Interacts with the database and performs your business logic, validation logic, etc.

Comment: This answer is a good one.  The only thing I would add is to consider your deployment/implementation concerns - are you happy having your view tier running in the same JVM as your busines/data tier?  Or, for instance, does your data tier need to sit behind a firewall?  If these aren't important to you, by all means put your focus on designing a good API and leave the exotic stuff for later.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler wrote a very nice article about the basics of REST short time ago: [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). Found it very helpful to understand the principles of REST.

Comment: thanks will read...though does this mean I completely botched the question?

Comment: ah ok :P it was definitely an insightful article.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use REST based backend services, you should use the [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/index.html) project which allows you you to use a GWT-RPC programing style to access your JSON based restful services.

The nice thing about using REST based JSON services over traditional GWT-RPC services is that those services can then be used by other clients or even in mashups more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using GWT-RPC instead of REST if you know you're going to be using GWT for the frontend.  More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775771/gwt-rpc-or-request-builder-using-javascript-overlay).

However, if you think you might want to eventually expose your data via a REST API, or use a different technology on the frontend, REST may be a better choice.

The [gwt-rest](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rest/) project may also be helpful.

Comment: thanks, I have considered both and REST was the ultimate decision based on the re-usability requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and I have written a GWT system using separate projects for front and back ends. It has been helpful to keep things quite clear about where the code is executing. But I'm not sure that I would bother separating things in a future system.

Also, given you're new to web development, I don't think you should be expecting to make a perfectly re-usable backend. You will learn lots of things as you go. I think that agile coders would recommend an iterative approach of (a) getting a small aspect working, and then (b) refactoring it to make it beautiful.